# Redis Session State Provider invalidate session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, caching, redis

I am using the ASP.Net Session state using the NuGet [RedisSessionStateProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider).

I am consuming the session data from the application using something like this:

```
public UserSessionData GetUserSessionData()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null || HttpContext.Current.Session["Key"] == null)
    {
        UserSessionData sessionData = ReadSessionFromDatabase();
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("Key", sessionData);
        return sessionData;
    }
    else
    {
        return (UserSessionData)HttpContext.Current.Session["Key"];
    }
}
```

With the method above, the first time the value is read from the Database and stored in the Session (Redis Cache). Next time the value is requested is read from Redis Cache without going to the SQL.

It works fine. Sometimes when I need to invalidate the values cached and force a read from the database I call `HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon()`. This is done as example when the user changes his plan.

Imagine a situation where I need to invalidate the cache because some change in the Database but this change is no trigger by the user. This change is done by another website (some internal website for manage users) or is done by a Webhook (a plan change notification for the user).How would you force the user to re again the data from the Database (delete cached data) when this is not trigger in the HttpContext?

I tested flushing all the redis cache with `flushdb` and it works. But off course it force all user session to read data again. How would you invalidate cache for only some user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do Session.Abandon() if you are inside application. But here you want to remove session from Redis from outside application. You can do that as long as you know application name (the one you provided inside web.config) and session id.

Session Data is stored inside Redis as _*Data and some supporting internal data is stored inside* *Internal. If user is concurrently running another page you might see* _Write_Lock.

If you remove all three from Redis it is basically equivalent of doing Session.Abandon(). If you are going to do this using C# program using StackExchange.Redis then I would recommend removing it using LUA script so all three will be removed at once and no other command can intervene.

You should have a place where you can find that database entry has been modified and run this code when necessary.

```html
string applicationName = "<Actual Application Name>";
string sessionId = "<Actual Session Id>";

RedisKey dataKey = String.Format("{0}_{1}_Data", applicationName, sessionId);
RedisKey internalKey = String.Format("{0}_{1}_Internal", applicationName, sessionId);
RedisKey writeLockKey = String.Format("{0}_{1}_Write_Lock", applicationName, sessionId);

RedisKey[] keys = new RedisKey[3];
keys[0] = dataKey;
keys[1] = internalKey;
keys[2] = writeLockKey;

string removeSessionScript = (@" 
    redis.call('DEL',KEYS[1])
    redis.call('DEL',KEYS[2])
    redis.call('DEL',KEYS[3])"
    );

db.ScriptEvaluate(removeSessionScript, keys, null);
```

Comment: An how do I know the Sesssion ID outside the app? As example get all IDs associated with a user.